# Will a second layer of landscape fabric impede water drainage?

Tags: concrete, drainage, landscaping, landscape

We bought a small wooden sandbox. It has no bottom and the entire thing sits on landscape liner.

**My questions is:**

**1.** Should I buy another layer of landscape fabric and staple it to the inside of the sandbox to keep sand in?

**And**
**2:** this sandbox is on a covered concrete patio. I'm wondering if the two landscape barriers will provide enough water/air flow?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have concerns about water and air flow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the *first* landscape fabric as you describe. Simply slice it diagonally, outward from the corners, and then bring the tabs inside the frame. Press them down into the corners and add a few staples or a lath on each side.

Water would drain through two layers of fabric, albeit more slowly. Airflow isn't really a thing here. There will be virtually none in either case, and the fact that it's under cover makes the issue moot anyway.